# how i do to find which thread fd(anon_inode、pipe) leak and fixed this bug

Tags: linux, linux-kernel, jetty, grpc

The system is running normally, but at 14:17, a large number of handles were started and they have been persisting without being released.

we want to find which thread is leak fd.

1. In our monitoring system, we use Linux commands(ls -al /proc//fd | wc -l) to monitor the number of handles for processes. We have found that the number of handles has increased dramatically, from 1000 to 3000.
2. Using commands(`ls -al /proc/<pid>/fd` ), we discovered that the number of handles increased by 2000 at 14:17.
   [pic](https://i.stack.imgur.com/XRA3j.png)

[pic](https://i.stack.imgur.com/QLobo.png)

[pic](https://i.stack.imgur.com/rwmNT.png)
3. We used the jstack command and found that the number of threads was normal at 1000.
[thread is screen](https://i.stack.imgur.com/5c4jO.png)
4. We used the jstrace command but could not find the corresponding thread.
strace -e trace=fcntl.epoll_ctl -f -t -o /opt/cad/strace_log.txt -p $pid

How can we locate the thread that is occupying the handle and not releasing it, and how can we fix it?

(we using jetty as selevet and communication with other service by grpc)